# Telnet Connection on java console

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, console, telnet

I am working on eclipse in a Linux OS and this is what i want to do (in the java console only)-

1. Connect to another remote machine via (currently) telnet client
2. execute a simple command in that remote system(something like ls)

Is that possible? I'm sure `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` wont work. So used the commons.net jar file. Here is my code snippet

```
public static void testMount() throws Exception {
    String osName = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
    System.out.println("Operating System: ");
    osName = sc.next();
    System.out.println(osName);
    String volumeToMount = "";
    String mountPoint = "";
    String ipAddress = "";
    int port = 23;

    if (osName.equalsIgnoreCase("Linux")) {
        // Linux
        ipAddress = "1.2.3.4"; //
        telnet.connect(ipAddress, port);
        volumeToMount = "/dev/hda1";
        mountPoint = "/data/Temp";
    } 
    mountFileSystem(volumeToMount, mountPoint);
}
```

If you have an existing example or if could modify my code, I'd be thankful to you if you share it over here!

Answer (score 4):

With Apache Commons Net `TelnetClient` you must use the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` returned by the object (see `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` method) to read data and send data (commands). A nice example is available [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=40) (see section **Telnet and Commons/NET**).

Comment: Thanks a lot..The connection got established. But i'm not able to interact by giving commands like ls or cd /tmp etc...

Comment: @hari: why not? have you looked at the example that I linked (using `TelnetClient` `getgetInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()`? If yes, What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error. But after logging in, i give ls command,and nothing happens.The execution doesn't terminate either.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual code. How do you give the `ls` command?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you implementing Telnet yourself? There are several libraries that do it very well. Take a look on Jakarta Net package: http://commons.apache.org/net/

Comment: he's using org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient   just omitted the import statement for brevity.